# Stack paragraphs inside a table cell, so they don't take that much height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with several cells. My table currently looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Students</th>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Math</td>
  </tr>
  <td><p> Student 1</p><p> Student 2</p>...</td>
</table>
```

My problem here is that the list of students can be very large. I would like to be able to say, ok, if there are more than 50 students, create another subcolumn inside this cell for the rest of the students.

So, right now the students are shown within the cell like this:

```
Student1
Student2
Student3
Student4
Student5
Student6
Student7
Student8
Student9
```

How could I make it so that is shown like this:

```
Student1   Student6
Student2   Student7
Student3   Student8
Student4   Student9
Student5
```

From within the same  cell?

Comment: How are you creating the table?

Comment: you mean something like:` <td>student1</td> <td>student2</td> ... <td>studentN</td>`

Comment: I am setting the HTML in a PHP var and then echoing it (it's a wordpress shortcode).

Comment: I dont understand what a sub column is.

Comment: I'd put the cell contents in a div with something like `max-height: 100px; overflow: auto` instead.

Comment: This is going to cause you so many headaches because you'll need to put a colspan on the "Math" <td> and if there's other classes with 50 or more students it will just get to be impossible to manage. You should use headers and lists. Also, your column headers don't make sense with your approach.

Comment: @JanTuroň Good idea. However, doing that creates a scroll button in the cell itself...It does not stack the other users to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I read through the comments and I think your approach using a table will bite you in the ass big time. I am not sure what browsers you need to support but `column-count` can make this pretty trivial.

It's essentially putting your students in a list and doing `column-count: 3`.

Here is the demo I came up with: http://jsbin.com/napam/1/edit

Comment: you can use autoprefixer, so no need to visit jsbin via only webkit http://jsbin.com/hoyeciya/1/edit , thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something simpler, see my comment to your question, or something like `td p { float: left; width: 150px; }`.

But if you really want it that way, create floating divs in the cell, fill them with buffer of 5 students...

```
var students = ["seth","dave","bob","kamil","yusuf","phil","luke","mike","ronald"];

function createDiv(contents) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.cssFloat = "left";
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.innerHTML = contents;
    return div;
}

var buffer = "", counter = 0;
var list = document.getElementById("list");
students.forEach(function(student) {
    buffer+= student+"<br>";
    if(counter==4) {
        list.appendChild(createDiv(buffer));
        buffer = "";
    }
    counter = ++counter%5;
});
if(buffer) list.appendChild(createDiv(buffer));
```

I assume `list` to be your target cell:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="list"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5Y2v/).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a list and dispatch your `li` making them `float`.

if you want 3 col , make every 3 + 1 clear left to draw a new line .

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gAneG/

basicly:

```
 li {
  counter-increment : liste ;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:80px;
  float:left;
  display:inline;/*kills bullet*/
}
li:nth-child(3n+1){/* that makes 3 cols, and this : li:nth-child(4n+1)would  4 cols */
  clear:left;
}
```

---

i do not use `column`, because , Firefox seems to not handle it properly inside a `<table>`. See here why with Firefox : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/DBsFI/

Comment: This approach is a great fallback for what I posted, but the students would read from left to right instead of top to bottom like he's shooting for.

Comment: it is not a fallback if he uses a `table`, give a try to set `column` to `ul`  in `td` while using Firefox ;)

Comment: @BillCriswell here : second table using `column-width` and `height` http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/DBsFI/ . For the reading left to right is the most natural , i see no problem with that :)

Comment: I agree it's more natural! He was very specific about how the data should look, though.